# Python Relating k-means cluster to instance

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I've read the docs 
[here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html) as well as looking at [this](http://fromdatawithlove.thegovans.us/2013/05/clustering-using-scikit-learn.html) tutorial, but I am still missing something fundamental about using K-means in scikit-learn:

Say I have a dataset as such:

```
|UserName| Variable1 | Variable2 | Variable3 |  Cluster |
|  bob   |    1      |     3     |    7      |          |
|  joe   |    2      |     4     |    8      |          |
|  bill  |    1      |     6     |    4      |          |
```

Since K-means takes a numpy array I have to strip out the username and just use the numerical variables. But, after the clusters have been created how do I relate them back to each individual user for further analysis. I.e how would I fill the "Cluster" column with the corresponding cluster number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example, assuming you read the data into a list from file:

```
import sklearn.cluster
import numpy as np

data = [
    ['bob', 1, 3, 7],
    ['joe', 2, 4, 8],
    ['bill', 1, 6, 4],
]

labels = [x[0] for x in data]
a = np.array([x[1:] for x in data])
clust_centers = 2

model = sklearn.cluster.k_means(a, clust_centers)
```

model now contains a tuple with (centroids, labels, intertia)

So get the labels back like this:

```
clusters = dict(zip(lables, model[1]))
```

And to print the cluster id for 'one':

```
print clusters['bob']
```

Or send it back out to a csv like this:

```
for d in data:
    print '%s,%d' % (','.join([str(x) for x in d]), clusters[d[0]])
```

Comment: strange... this worked once, but on the second time through after `model = sklearn.cluster.k_means(a, clust_centers)` I get a `ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'DOUBLE' but got 'float'
` error

Comment: Hmm, how'd you run the script?  It sounds like the dtype of 'a' got corrupted somehow.

Comment: running it on Ubuntu 12.04 using built in python 2.7. I opened another question for this as google is failing me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21220131/dtype-mismatch-in-sklearn-on-k-means

Comment: reran it on a different machine (this one has Anaconda installed) and it worked in that environment

Answer (score 1):

I am reminded of the time when I had to face the exact same issue. :-)

Here is what I know. When you feed in the data matrix X into KMeans (or any of sklearn's algorithms for that matter), the order is remembered. Let's say you create a KMeans clusterer:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

kms = KMeans().fit(X) #where X is your data
```

You can retrieve the labels as:

```
labels = list(kms.labels_)
```

The way I think is usually in lists or dictionaries, so I tend to cast many things as lists or arrays.

The order of the labels will be identical to your dataset. In other words, if `bob`'s data is in position `0` and so on, then `kms.labels_` will return the labels in the exact same order.

To put them together, either `zip` or `map`.